# How to implement 2 way scrolling- vertical and horizontal scrolling in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, uitableview

I want to implement a tab layout with a horizontal swipe or scroll view and in each tab view, I could be able to scroll vertically.
For reference just like WhatsApp where there are tab layouts that are horizontally scrollable or swipeable and in each tab layout, there is a vertical scroll view in kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

According to WhatsApp
let's assume, the horizontal scroll behaves for tab layout and each tab layout is a container. Inside each tablayout container, we can use a recyclerview, scrollview, listview any one of these for getting the vertical scroll behavior layout.

[image]

**#Say for example the image. The main screen contains a TabLayout and each TabLayout contain a Recyclerview that scrolls in the vertical direction.**

Comment: Really appreciated your effort, I have implemented recycler view in each tab layout but the problem is when I am setting the height of recyc;ler view as match parent then I am only able to scroll vertically as it is in the focus and when I am setting the height of viewpager2 as match parent then I am only able to swipe through the tabs. If you have any solutions for that please give. Thank you @Kawsar