# How to implement 2 way scrolling- vertical as well as horizontal scrolling in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, android-viewpager2

I want to implement a tab layout with a horizontal swipe or scroll view and in each tab view, I could be able to scroll vertically. For reference just like WhatsApp where there are tab layouts that are horizontally scrollable or swipeable and in each tab layout there is a vertical scroll view in kotlin.

Problem I am facing -

I have implemented the recycler view in each tab layout but the problem is when I am setting the height of the recycler view as match parent then I am only able to scroll vertically as it is in the focus and when I am setting the height of viewpager2 as match parent then I am only able to swipe through the tabs. If you have any solutions for that please give.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement 2 way scrolling- vertical and horizontal scrolling in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175316/how-to-implement-2-way-scrolling-vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-in-kotlin)

Comment: No not really @Andrew